# What is SP.dateTimeUtil.js?

Tags: 2010, calendar, date-time

I found SP.dateTimeUtil.js contains all date and calendar formats and modified one of them to customize display of dates but SP 2010 doesn't use this file anywhere. I need customized Calendar.aspx and Datepickers in all parts.

Answer (score 3):

`SP.dateTimeUtil.js` provides [methods for working with dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411030(v=office.14).aspx).

It is **not** supposed to be modified since it is a part of [SharePoint JS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538253(v=office.14).aspx).

Consider [Regional Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824907(v=office.14).aspx) to customize the calendar, time format and etc.